# Problem setting component attribute

Tags: component, lightning-radiogroup

I am having trouble doing a basic task of setting a component attribute in my controller.  I define the attribute in the component, get the value of the radio button option selected & want to set the value of the attribute.  I am not able to set the attribute.

Main component

```
            <lightning:radioGroup aura:id="amountDueRadioButton" 
                          label="Select a registration Option"
                          name="registrationOption"
                          checked="{!v.amountDue}" 
                          onchange="{!c.calculateAmountDue}"                       
                          type="radio"
                          options="{! v.registrationOptions }"
                              required="true"/>
```

Controller

```
        calculateAmountDue: function(component, event, helper) {
             var registrationOption = event.getSource().get("v.value");
             if (registrationOption=="Open Day ONLY") {
             alert("before component set");  ** this works **
             component.set("v.amountDue", 10);
             alert("after component set"); *never get to this **
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is no `checked` attribute for [`lightning:radioGroup`.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:radioGroup/specification) So that might be causing the error and you need to remove it.

> `checked="{!v.amountDue}`

If you want to set a value, you can use `value="{!v.amountDue}"`. Make sure the value you are setting is available in the list of options you are providing.

Comment: That fixed it!!!!  Thank you  @manjit5190